# Equation of a circle with unknowns

Tags: geometry, circles

The circle $x^2+y^2-a^2x+ay-22=0$ contains point $Q(2,4)$. Find value of $a$. I have subbed in the points for $x$ and $y$ but how do I get rid of the $a^2$?

I have $a^2-2a=1$

Comment: I get $a^2 -2a+1 =0$

Comment: $x^2+y^2-a^2x+ay-22=0\land x=2 \land y=4 \Rightarrow$ $4+16-2a^2+4a-22=0\Rightarrow$ $-2a^2+4a-2=0 \Rightarrow$ $a^2-2a+1=0 \Rightarrow$ $(a-1)^2=0 \Rightarrow \ldots$

Answer (score 1):

As your question states. You will need to find $a$. Solve the equation you came up with (you did a typo) and you are done.